# Ubuntu one synchronization problems after reinstallation of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one, re-installation, deja-dup

Installed U1 on my Ubuntu 11.10, synchronized flawlessly towards my smartphone. Wanted to get rid of Windows as second OS,and backed up by Deja Dup and reinstalled Ubuntu 11.10.

After synchronization did not work properly. Synchronized folders in Home directory reported: This folder is backed up and will be synchronized with the other computer. No other computer on the net. refers probably to the previous installation of U10.11.

How can I get my Home folders synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

First Ubuntu One will not sync your home folders. It only syncs ~/Ubuntu One by default and will (optionally) sync other folders under your home folder. If you synced various folders (not talking about deja dup) with Ubuntu One they will not automatically sync when you reinstall your OS. You will need to select them using the Ubuntu One Control Panal.

If you are referring to Deja Dup's *backup* of your files, that application puts them in a special folder in Ubuntu One which does not sync (and I do not recommend you do). You can view them online at https://one.ubuntu.com/files